# Change menu Title after clicking.

Tags: android, menu

I created a Menu and I can access it. there is no problem. But I need to change the Menu Item's name after clicking on the menu

Comment: Niek @No_Rulz answer is working fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case 1:
item.setTitle("your char");
}}
```